# failing to install angular material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am new to Angular 2 and Material. I've got Ang2 installed -using ang-cli and am now trying to get a basic Material "Hello World" going.

I'm following their install here:
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/getting-started.md
I am on Step 2.

I've npm installed the animations but I'm not sure how to add the reference.

It doesn't say where to add that code block, so I am adding it to the app.module.ts file, thus:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
// added:
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; // added


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule // added
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

// added
@NgModule({ 
    imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule],
})
export class PizzaPartyAppModule { }
```

So, I get a few errors when I do this.

@angular/platform-browser/animations tells me (with a red squiggly underline) that it 'Cannot find module **'@angular/platform-browser/animations'**'

I look in my folder structure and I find this:

- @angular

  - animations
  - platform-browser
  - - (no animations folder in here)

So I change **@angular/platform-browser/animations** to **@angular/animations**

And now BrowserAnimationsModule is telling me (with a red squiggly underline) that **Module angular/animations/animations has no exported member BrowserAnimationsModule**.

I'm not sure what it wants.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem to this a little while ago.  My issue stemmed from the fact that I was using Angular Material 2, which had dependencies on Angular 4.  Angular 4 removes the animations module from its core for efficiency.  There seems to be issues with that.  You may want to update your project from Angular 2to Angular 4 (which isn't as app breaking as it may sound). I think this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have "Ang2 installed". If that's the case, any material release after 2.0.0-beta.2 will not work with Angular 2. You can read material's changelog  for beta.3 below.

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

To get material to work with Angular 2.x.x, you have to install the beta.2 version.

```
npm install @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.2 --save
```

Then, go to your app.module.ts, import Material Module and add it in the imports array.

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
   imports: [
     MaterialModule
   ]
})
```

If you have installed Angular 4, then you are on correct path by following getting started guide.
I would suggest run these steps again:

```
npm install --save @angular/material
npm install --save @angular/animations

import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule],
    ...
  })
```

Whichever material component you decide to use, also needs to be imported.

```
import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule, 
              NoopAnimationsModule, 
              MdButtonModule, 
              MdCheckboxModule
             ],
    ...
    })
```

Let me know, if this helps.